# filling a buffered chan until gets full or a time duration passes

Tags: go

i have a `chan string` which is buffered, i keep filling it with random strings until a time.Duration passes or until it gets full.

my question is should i use a ticker for that considering that its a one time task or is there a more convienient way?

here is my current way of doing it

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    res := fillChan(time.Duration(1*time.Nanosecond), 100000)
    fmt.Println(len(res))
}

func fillChan(maxDuration time.Duration, chanSize int) chan string {
    c := make(chan string, chanSize)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(maxDuration)

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            ticker.Stop()
            return c
        case c <- "Random message":
        default:
            return c
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in Go (in fact, I've never used it), but the documentation suggests [`Timer`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer), or [`After`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) for single events.

```
select {
case <-time.After(1*time.Nanosecond):
    return c
case c <- "Random message":
default:
    return c
}
```