# timing out with time.After does not behave like timing out with a ticker or a timer

Tags: go

I expect the follwoing to functions to behave the same way

```
func fillChanTimeoutUsingTicker(maxDuration time.Duration, chanSize int) chan string {
    c := make(chan string, chanSize)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(maxDuration)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            ticker.Stop()
            fmt.Println("Ticker:operation timedout")
            return c
        case c <- "Random message":
        default:
            fmt.Println("Ticker:chan is full")
            return c
        }
    }
}

func fillChanTimeoutUsingTimeAfter(maxDuration time.Duration, chanSize int) chan string {
    c := make(chan string, chanSize)
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(maxDuration):
            fmt.Println("time.After:operation timedout")
            return c
        case c <- "Random message":
        default:
            fmt.Println("time.After:chan is full")
            return c
        }
    }
}
```

calling them as :

```
    resWithTicker := fillChanTimeoutUsingTicker(time.Duration(1*time.Microsecond), 10000000)
    fmt.Println(len(resWithTicker))
    resWithTimeAfter := fillChanTimeoutUsingTimeAfter(time.Duration(1*time.Microsecond), 10000000)
    fmt.Println(len(resWithTimeAfter))
```

prints:

```
Ticker:operation timedout
43979
time.After:chan is full
10000000
```

i thought that they would behave exactly the same way and i really don't get the huge difference, any thoughts on this?

note also using a timer works as expected like in the ticker function.

Comment: This is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666182/filling-a-buffered-chan-until-gets-full-or-a-time-duration-passes, should it just have been an addendum/edit to that question rather than a new question? (I had been about to comment on [an answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32666358/55504) to point out this exact issue before I noticed this separate question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within your code.

In your first example, you are creating *one* ticker and use that for timing out.
In your second example, you create a timer **every time you loop**:

```
case <-time.After(maxDuration):
```

As can be seen in the [library sources](http://golang.org/src/time/sleep.go?s=3012:3046#L99), this is equivalent to

```
case <- time.NewTimer(maxDuration).C:
```

If you create a new Ticker/Timer every time you loop (and discard the old one), it will probably never fire.

So, to get your second example to behave correctly, do it like this (untested):

```
func fillChanTimeoutUsingTimeAfter(maxDuration time.Duration, chanSize int) chan string {
    c := make(chan string, chanSize)
    t := time.After(maxDuration)
    for {
        select {
        case <-t:
            fmt.Println("time.After:operation timedout")
            return c
        case c <- "Random message":
        default:
            fmt.Println("time.After:chan is full")
            return c
        }
    }
}
```